# React router dom full page reload

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I have just created a fresh react project with **create-react-app** . for navigation i am using **react-router-dom** in my `index.js` file i have wraped `App.js` components with  and in `App.js` i am using switch component to load pages based on changes in URL . its working fine , the problem is that it loads whole page when i change url from /auth to / which is not desired behaviour

Following is my `index.js` file

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter forceRefresh={false}>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);

// If you want your app to work offline and load faster, you can change
// unregister() to register() below. Note this comes with some pitfalls.
// Learn more about service workers: 
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Following is my `App.js` file

```js
import React from "react";
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Link, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import HomePage from "./pages/home";
import AuthPage from "./pages/auth";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/auth" render={(props) => <AuthPage {...props} />} />
        <Route path="/" exact render={(props) => <HomePage {...props} />} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

desired behaviour is that when i change url in the browser from keyboard it should not reload whole page . it should just reload the App div in `App.js`

Comment: can you please mention how you are changing the browser URL

Comment: If you enter the url in the browser by keyboard, it will always refresh your App. If you want not to, you need to use a ```NavLink``` ,```Link``` or ```Redirect``` component from ```react-router-dom```. Of course this are clickable elements, beside ```Redirect``` which triggers automatically.

Comment: i am changing url by typing in browser URL area

Comment: i have only 2 pages in my app . a login page and home page . that is why i am not using any navigation bars . i want to know if i change the pages programatically than it will not reload whole page  right ?